# How to reduce filesize of gradient PNG?

Tags: png, image-compression

I am trying to create a background image on a webpage, which is similar to the 404 page used on tumbler...

http://testing404image.tumblr.com/

Here we can see a PNG which is 1623*1064 pixels, yet appears reasonably smooth gradient wise.
The direct link for the image is 
http://testing404image.tumblr.com/images/status_bg.png?2

When I try to create a similar PNG (different colors, but same size) in Photoshop CS4 for Mac, the resulting file ends up at > 400k, whereas tumblers is 90k

Ive tried playing with all Photoshop options, including reducing number of colors to 55, but I cannot get the image below ~240k.

Ive also tried various optimising tools such as ImageOptim (http://imageoptim.com/) but to no avail.

Are there any properties of this PNG which result in a such a low file size?
I tried using JPG, thinking its better suited to gradient images, but even a 100% quality JPG resulted in noticeable aliasing, which an identical content/size PNG didnt have.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there changed the colours with

> Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation - In Photoshop CS4

and this is the result:

[image]

as you can see it's almost the same size (75k).

Try playing around under the

> Image > Adjustments

to get the color you are looking for and save as png with NONE for interlace.

Comment: Thanks, I did try to adjust tumblrs version initially, but since the color Im using is dark red, it looked very ropey. I've since used Hue/Saturation + Colorize, then some other options in Adjustments, and managed to get something usable around the same size

Comment: Glad to help. BTW why do you need the resolution to be that huge?

Comment: @carpii why did you accepted this as an answer? despite it's helpful to you but it is not actually answering the question in the title. I am posting the real answer right now.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop is not very good with PNG: I simply opened and saved it with the humble xnView (maximum compression), and got 74K. You can also convert it to paletted-image, and do some extra little tuning - PNGoptim gives me a final size of 64.548. I would't expect anything much better than that, the image is just too big.

BTW, be aware that using a gradient that is so big and so smooth that it a digital image (with 8 bits per pixel) cannot represent it without some banding. That image is really oversampled (you could resample it at 25% or less and  display it scaled, and the result would be basically the same)

Comment: Thanks, I tried other tools too, but they resulted in similar file sizes (when creating it from scratch). I think PNG is not the bets file format for this, but still Ive been unable to reproduce tumblrs gradient form scratch, in less than 250k

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason is the source image your looking to have a lower gradient quality than the one you are making.

Just uncheck the `Dither` option (from the top toolbar in Photoshop) when filling the gradient color. the quality and smoothness of the gradient is decreased and therefore you get a very smaller file sized PNG output.